# How to get User from CanCan Ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In CanCan, an ability is assigned to an individual user.  Is there a way to access that user when you have an ability record.

I'd like to be able to say:

```
@ability = Ability.new(User.find(3))
@ability.based_on_user # Does not exist, but would respond with the same thing as User.find(3)
```

In my app, users can impersonate other users, which involves resetting `@current_ability = Ability.new(@impersonated_user)` and I'd like to be able to quickly get that user for debugging purposes.  The documentation doesn't give any such method, but I would be okay with a hack, since it's just for my own purposes in testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that method yourself to your ability model. Something like this:

```
# in app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
     @user = user

     # the rest of your code
   end

   def based_on_user
     @user
   end
end
```